# MAX-LP: maximize number of linear inequalities satisfied

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, linear-programming

Consider the following variant of linear programming, where we want to maximize the number of linear inequalities that are satisfied:

Input: linear inequalities $A_1x\le b_1$, ..., $A_nx \le b_n$; an integer $k$
Output: does there exist $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ that satisfies at least $k$ of these linear inequalities?

To make the problem well-defined, we can assume everything is in $\mathbb{Q}$.

What is the complexity of this problem?  It smells like it must surely be hard, but I cannot see how to prove it.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/115216/755

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this is NP-hard.  It is known as the maximum feasible subsystem problem (Max-FS).  Max-FS is NP-hard. There is an approximation algorithm with approximation factor 2, but it does not admit a PTAS unless P=NP.

See

[The Complexity and Approximability of Finding
Maximum Feasible Subsystems of Linear Relations](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.43.9283&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Edoardo Amaldi and Viggo Kann.  Theoretical computer science, 147(1-2), 1995, pp.181-210.